# Accuracy vs. probability in confidence interval

Tags: confidence-interval

I have a little doubt regarding the confidence intervals.

I know that if I enlarge the sample size, then the amplitude of the interval will be smaller, therefore, the interval will be more **precise**, but I also think that, as a result of this, the probability that the confidence interval will be correct will be lower since the area under the curve(confidence level) between a narrower interval will be smaller.

So, I can say this?:

If the sample size grows, the accuracy of the interval will increase, however the probability of success of the interval will decrease.

[image]

[image]

Comment: As far as the commonly adopted practice goes, increasing the sample size does NOT lower the confidence level. The confidence level $\alpha$ is fixed by construction.

Comment: @LeeDavidChungLin I know this property: If the amplitude of the interval decreases, the level of confidence decreases. According to that, i can say that if the sample size increases, the amplitude decreases, therefore the confidence level decrease. So why do you say it doesn't affect?

Comment: Usually the interval is constructed for a fixed $\alpha$. If in your application the interval is constructed with something else fixed, then that's a different story.